# angularjs fire promise and redirect to external URL before it resolves

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

In my angular app I have a final page in a flow which asks the person completing a questionnaire if they would like additional information and if so to enter their email address. When they press the button to submit their email address I would like to immediately redirect them to an external website (this page changes per questionnaire and is always likely to be one of our client's public web pages).

The submit method can take a little while to complete as it has to generate a relatively complex report and attach it to an email and then send that email (not to the person that pressed submit).

In theory I don't need to wait for the submit method to finish before redirecting the user and I would ideally like to do it straight away before the promise resolves.

The below code does this:

```
requestReportPromiseCall(emailAddress);
this.$window.location.href = this.MasterPageService.Reseller.forwardingWebsiteUrl;
```

As you can see there is no ".then(() => {}" and whilst this technically works it throws an error which you can see in the dev tools:

> localhost:3000/assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js:123 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse"...

I think I understand why this happens but I wondered if there was a better way of doing this so no error occurs or maybe even changing the method so it doesn't wait for the response (maybe making the email sending API method work like an async method)?

Comment: If you leave the page, any in-progress requests will be canceled.

Comment: That's definitely in the right ball park. I think with that in mind the only way I can properly do this is add the request to a queue and send back a completed response once it's been queued although this is a bit more work than I had planned to take on for now but not sure there's a better or easier way.

Comment: Sounds like a solid plan; respond immediately and delegate the actual work to another process.